# Синхронизация группы объектов

Tags: java, многопоточность

Доброго времени суток.

**С чем имеем дело:**

Есть список объектов(ArrayList). К объектам списка очень часто (60 и более раз в секунду) обращаются несколько потоков. Каждый поток обращаясь к объекту выполняет над ним операцию которая может занять очень много времени. Необходимо синхронизировать работу потоков с этой коллекцией.

**Как я пытался решить задачу:**

1. самое первое решение: делать синхронизацию на уровне самой коллекции, т.е. пока один поток работает с коллекцией - другие ждут его. Но у каждого из потоков есть операции над объектом, которые могут занять очень много времени(несколько секунд), и как итог, программа стала сильно виснуть.
2. Далее я заметил - некоторые из потоков никогда не обращаются ко всем объектам коллекции сразу, а обращаются к небольшой группе(состав и размер группы объектов, с которыми может работать потоком все время меняется.). Решил делать синхронизацию на уровне каждого отдельного объекта, т.е. пока поток 1 занимается одним объектом, другим потокам ничего не мешает заниматься другими. Но тут появились сложности связанные с необходимостью работы с группой объектов как с одним целым.

**Вопрос:**

Предположим есть группа из 4 объектов (A, B, C, D). Поток 1 синхронизируется на этой группе и пока он занят работой с объектом A, другие потоки не могут получить доступ не только к объекту A, но и к объектам B, C и D. При этом - пытаясь получить доступ, скажем к объекту B, другой поток будет заблокирован(как при попытке захватить занятый монитор) до тех пор, пока поток работающий с группой не закончит работу СО ВСЕМИ объектами из группы. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Если потоки работают с непересекающимися подмножествами массива, то могу предложить следующий вариант - в общем для всех потоков синхронизированном методе (или блоке) очередной поток "забирает" к себе "незабранные" элементы массива и освобождает блок для очередного потока - это быстрая операция. После обработки этих элементов каждый поток вызывает другой синхронизированный метод для возврата элементов на место в общем массиве. Соответственно, позиции забранных элементов  в массиве помечается как-нибудь, например null-ом.

Comment: Спасибо, Alexander Cherin. Идея с null метками мне понравилась. Но можно ли сделать так, чтобы другой поток который попытается работать с одним из объектов группы над которой уже работает другой поток - блокировался и ждал пока поток работающий с группой не завершит свои дела? При этом хотелось бы обойтись без wait().

Comment: Если очередной поток обнаруживает "свой"  элемент массива, в обработке у другого потока, то либо он уходит по своим делам, либо регистрируется у этого чужого потока в качестве слушателя, а сам встаёт в wait. При этом тот другой поток, обработав элемент, вызывает notify всем ожидающим элемент потокам. Без wait не обойтись

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент, воспользовавшись советом выше, я нашел решение с помощью Reentrantlock. Решение следующие - каждый критический метод синхронизируется с помощью ReetrantLock(также, как мы бы это делали с помощью synchronized). Далее создаем ещё два метода - lock() и unlock() которые делегируют вызов соответствующим методам ReentrantLock. Когда поток собирается работать с группой объектов, он предварительно вызывает lock() у каждого объекта, далее работает с ними, а после завершения работы вызывает unlock() у каждого объекта. Мне не нравится это решение, поскольку можно легко выстрелить себе в ногу, но оно рабочее, простое в реализации и должно быть быстрее вариантов с wait(). А чтобы не было deathlock необходимо захватывать объекты всегда в одном и том же порядке(как написали выше в коментариях).

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужна не *synchronized collection*, а *concurrent collection*, то есть блокировка не всей коллекции при работе с ним, а конкретного элемента коллекции.

Таковым является [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Существенным минусом данной реализации является то что при операции вставки/удаления будет производиться полная копия списка (поэтому он так и называется `CopyOnWriteArrayList`), если у вас операции удаления/добавления в список редкие, то это рабочий вариант.

Если не подходит, то надо пересмотреть коллекцию на что-то другое, например `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`

Comment: На сколько я понял - коллекция CopyOnWriteArrayList не сихронизирует сами хранящиеся в ней элементы(а мне нужно именно это), а синхронизирует операции изменяющие саму коллекцию. Я прав? Я верно вас понял?